# Google Spreadsheet Upload certificate verify failed

Tags: python, python-2.7, openssl, intel-galileo

I'm currently working on uploading sensor data to Google Spreadsheet through Intel Galileo board. Everything works perfectly fine in my Ubuntu but get some trust issues when I move everything to the board.
It keeps returning

> Google sheet login failed with error: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:504: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed

I followed many ways and workarounds but nothing seems to fit this error like skip the verification (security isn't matter, at least to me), install a bunch of suggested packages, etc.

Any help in detail would be very much appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You will always get a warning message about the certificate even if you set verify to False. But it will still work. The Galileo board will need Google's CA cert (it probably has none at all) to get rid of the message.

you can get them [here](https://pki.google.com/)

Comment: You're laptop will have a CA bundle somwhere. The board likely does not. I am not sure where requests looks for its CA certs. Bu thats where the cert will need to be put.